# Sorting a List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, list

Using C# what is the best way to sort a List numerically?
my list has items 5,7,3 and I would like them sorted 3,5,7.  I know some longer ways, but I would imagine linq has a quicker way?

sorry this was end of day, my mind is else where it worked, didn't see it change the first time:(

Comment: In case if Integers are Strings you could use this great approach http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html

Answer (score 187, accepted):

There's no need for LINQ here, just call `Sort`:

```
list.Sort();
```

Example code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 5, 7, 3 };
list.Sort();
foreach (int x in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Result:

```
3
5
7
```

Comment: sorry end of day, I was viewing it before the sort took place :( home time i suppose

Comment: I can't find any documention saying that it sorts in ascending order, am I just being paranoid in saying that we can't assume it will always be in ascending order? Who knows maybe 20 years from now people will always assume descending makes more sense and and this assumption will be the new y2k

Comment: Great solution, but bad thing Sort() is return type void  - not chainable therefore... Used @Will s answer instead.

Comment: For @truthof42 : The Sort method with no parameter overload uses default comparer. For example int32 class implements IComparer interface that defines how to compare two instances. That is the default comparer. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/comparisons-and-sorts-within-collections#determine-sort-order

Answer (score 50):

Keeping it simple is the key.

Try Below.

```
var values = new int[5,7,3];
values = values.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 19):

```
var values = new int[] {5,7,3};
var sortedValues = values.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();   // result 3,5,7
```

Answer (score 12):

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 5, 7, 3 };  
list.Sort((x,y)=> y.CompareTo(x));  
list.ForEach(action => { Console.Write(action + " "); });
```

Answer (score 8):

Sort a list of integers descending

```
class Program
    {       
        private class SortIntDescending : IComparer<int>
        {
            int IComparer<int>.Compare(int a, int b) //implement Compare
            {              
                if (a > b)
                    return -1; //normally greater than = 1
                if (a < b)
                    return 1; // normally smaller than = -1
                else
                    return 0; // equal
            }
        }

        static List<int> intlist = new List<int>(); // make a list

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            intlist.Add(5); //fill the list with 5 ints
            intlist.Add(3);
            intlist.Add(5);
            intlist.Add(15);
            intlist.Add(7);

            Console.WriteLine("Unsorted list :");
            Printlist(intlist);

            Console.WriteLine();
            // intlist.Sort(); uses the default Comparer, which is ascending
            intlist.Sort(new SortIntDescending()); //sort descending

            Console.WriteLine("Sorted descending list :");
            Printlist(intlist);

            Console.ReadKey(); //wait for keydown
        }

        static void Printlist(List<int> L)
        {
            foreach (int i in L) //print on the console
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: outstanding example of a custom comparator!

Answer (score 8):

Sort list of int descending you could just sort first and reverse

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> myList = new List<int>();

        myList.Add(38);
        myList.Add(34);
        myList.Add(35);
        myList.Add(36);
        myList.Add(37);


        myList.Sort();
        myList.Reverse();
        myList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);


    }



}
```

Comment: Sort list of int descending you could just sort first and reverse

Comment: It would help the OP if you were to give an explanation as to what your answer is/does and how it helps solve their issue. Append your comment to your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
double jhon = 3;
double[] numbers = new double[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

{
    numbers[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

}
Console.WriteLine("\n");

Array.Sort(numbers);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to give an explanation as to why this should fix OP's problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.