# In C#, Procedure that modifies incoming array by reversing it?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem in particular.

Write a procedure that modifies the incoming array of ints by reversing it. Because this is a procedure, it will not return anything. Instead, I will have to modify the array directly, and because arrays are reference type variables, the array will be permanently changed even after this procedure. To reverse an array, imagine the array with an imaginary line in the middle of it, and then swap the numbers on the left with the numbers on the right side.

At the moment, this is the only code I've written down for the problem. Based on the code I've written so far, I don't think I'm approaching it towards the correct solution for it.

```
public void Test10(int[] numbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Consider what happens if, given the list `[1,2,3,4]`, you swap the two far ends, giving `[4,2,3,1]`, then swap the two inner items, giving `[4,3,2,1]`. Write code to do that.

Comment: you can use linq to sort it, better learn linq , will be very handy in the future

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738639/sorting-a-listint       linq to sort int array

Comment: @ARUN Using LINQ for trivial things like sorting is overkill and should not be encouraged

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'd love to see your source on that...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen okay, i see from performance point of view

Comment: @DavidL It is common sense. Sure, LINQ sort may use the exact same operation under the hood, but is still complexity over just calling the already existing Sort method. There are so many examples of people pushing LINQ for trivial things where it adds dependencies and complexity. It also makes people not realize what's happening under the hood. Of course that's a problem already in copypasta code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, it's called not utilizing the tools you already have in front of you.  If Linq is already available to the project (and I can't think of a project I've touched in years where it isn't) and if Lilnq is not a performance hit (and many have proven it is not) and if Linq provides a consistent, maintainable, readable experience for other developers who will be supporting your code downstream, then there's absolutely zero reason to avoid it for anything other than what I could call a purely pragmatic argument.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Keep in mind that I am NOT advocating that it is superior to Array.Reverse.  But your argument to avoid it because it is overkill is also unfounded.  It 99% of modern C# codebases it could hardly be considered overkill.

Comment: @DavidL So not knowing what it actually does or if it is a performance problem is OK? I'm simply talking about these simple cases, not saying not to use LINQ at all. But this really is a discussion for another place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use built-in `Array.Reverse` method, which reverses the sequence of the elements in the entire one-dimensional Array.

```
 Array.Reverse(array); // reverse supplied array
```

Please note, `System.Array.Reverse()` does in place transformation.

Comment: this is a good one!! also because this will probably not suffice the obviously homework task...

Comment: so Array.Reverse() will go between the for loop?

Comment: You don't need any loop, just pass an input array, and your array will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options based on your preference and need

```
int[] array = {1,3};
Array.Reverse(array);
```

This will reverse the original array

```
 int[] array = {1,3};
 var reversedArray = array.Reverse().ToArray();
```

This will use linq and new reversed array will be returned and original array will remain as it is