# How to sort a list of enums by the enum indexes in C#?

Tags: c#, list, enums

I have an `enum`:

```
public enum Group
{
    Administration = 1,
    Lawyers,
    PropertyManagement
    Bookkeeping,
    Secretariat
}
```

I have a `List` of `Group` also: `List<Group>`. I need a simple way to sort the values of the list by the enum index.

So, for example, this list:

```
{ Group.Bookkeeping, Group.Administration, Group.Secretariat, Group.Administration }
```

Will become:

```
{ Group.Administration, Group.Administration, Group.Bookkeeping, Group.Secretariat }
```

(Administration first, bookkeeping second, secretariat last, like in the definition of the enum). I am looking for a simple way (maybe using `linq`), without manually looping or so.

Comment: You could use inheritance rather than `Enum` which will give you benefits in the long run.

Comment: @Callum I don't see how inheritance is relevant here.

Comment: I'm looking more to the fact that, he is using enums to describe a certain object which in turn describes a real life domain . Where as, you could eliminate some horrible code (such as if, switches) by using inheritance to describe that real life domain. So make a Administrator an actual object (because administrators are different to bookkeepers) @CodeCaster

Comment: @Callum you use inheritance to describe and implement difference in _behavior_. This question does not mention any of that.

Comment: I know, I'm reading beyond the question @CodeCaster

Comment: @Callum no, you're applying a blanket statement that doesn't help the OP nor future visitors. Inheritance has its place, and this is not it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117693/discussion-between-callum-linington-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.Sort()` uses the underlying type by default to compare the elements:

```
List<Group> groups = new List<Group>()
{
    Group.Bookkeeping, Group.Administration, Group.Secretariat, Group.Administration
};

groups.Sort();
```

Comment: You really understood what I misunderstood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is basically an integral type, and its members gets numbered starting from 0 and incrementing by 1 by default. Given you've supplied a starting index, namely `Administration = 1`, your enum is numbered as follows:

```
Administration = 1
Lawyers = 2
PropertyManagement = 3
Bookkeeping = 4
Secretariat = 5
```

So you can simply sort using the default sort for the collection, as explained in [Sorting a List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738639/sorting-a-listint).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linqs `OrderBy`:

```
List<Group> orderedGroups = groups.OrderBy(g => g).ToList();
```