# Find the index of the highest numbers in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of integers and I want to find out the position of the biggest integer in my list.

```
List<int> members = new List<int>({312, 33, 122, 3979, 8712, 88})
```

I tried getting the biggest number by doing `int max = members.Max();` and then I tried to get its index like this `int highestMember = members.FindIndex(max);` but it doesn't work this way

Comment: why not sort the list and call the last item in the index? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738639/sorting-a-listint

Comment: If you are interesting in finding "index of element in a list" you may want to consider using search engine. Since the one you usually use probably did not find anything useful you can try one provided by the same company that build C# and VS for you - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+index+of+element+in+list

Comment: So it should be IndexOf instead of FindIndex. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try :

```
List<int> members = new List<int> { 312, 33, 122, 3979, 8712, 8888 };
int a = members.IndexOf(members.Max());
```