# Sort even numbers from List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to display even numbers from a list of integers and sort them in ascending order. My code is:

```cs
public void EvenNumbers()
{
    List<int> ofNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2, 10, 15, 6, 8 };

    ofNumbers.Sort();
    var result = (from m in ofNumbers
                  where m % 2 == 0
                  select m).ToList();
}
```

But after reading [Sorting a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738639/sorting-a-listint) I am trying to sort my list with the following code:

```cs
var values = new int[] { 5,7,3 };
values = values.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

changing my code to this is not working

```cs
public void EvenNumbers()
{
    List<int> ofNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2, 10, 15, 6, 8 };
    
    var result = ofNumbers.OrderBy(from m in ofNumbers
                  where m % 2 == 0
                  select m).ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot oder a list by a list. `OrderBy` expects a `Predicate<T>`, which is similar to a `Func<T, bool>`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`. In other words: filter **before** (or after) you sort, not **while** you sort.

Comment: `ofNumbers.Where(m => m % 2 == 0).OrderBy(m => m).ToList();`

Comment: read more about orderby https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavRyumkin it works, I can accept your answer, unfortunately, I can't rate but I can accept if you answer me properly.

Comment: Thanks, @HimBromBeere for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing query syntax with method syntax. The query syntax looks really close to normal SQL:

```
var result = (from m in ofNumbers
              where m % 2 == 0
              orderby m
              select m).ToList();
```

The method syntax expects lambda expressions:

```
var result = ofNumbers.Where(m => m % 2 == 0).OrderBy(m => m).ToList();
```

Both are compiled to the very same IL, hence you can just take the version you like most. I think the query syntax is preferred by beginners, whereas the method syntax is preferred by advanced C# coders (because it is more powerful).

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is that you are trying to combine two syntaxes:

1. Extension methods syntax. (OrderBy() method)
2. Query syntax (from, where, select, etc. keywords)

It would be better to use just one approach. Here are examples:

Extension methods:

```cs
var result = ofNumbers.Where(m => m % 2 == 0).OrderBy(m => m).ToList();
```

Query:

```cs
var result = (from m in ofNumbers
                where m % 2 == 0
                orderby m
                select m).ToList();
```